# I use the DecimalFormat but cannot make the integer in the right format

Tags: java

```
float number = 1;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String str = ""+df.format(number);
fw.write(str);
```

I want to make the integer 1 be 1.00. But in the file str, it still writes 1 rather than 1.00. How to make it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use format `"#.00"`
Check [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Comment: I think the Symbol description in the end of the document is misleading. Because '0' will show the trailing zero of the right part of the decimal point, but '#' won't. Though the document shows correct examples.

Comment: What if the number is a normal float number? For example, number  = 1.233? Is there a method to show correct format for both cases?

Comment: I think you are confused. It's not about float or int. It's about precision and round-up. How many right side digits do you want to keep? If you want keep at-least 2 digits, and plus one only if it's not zero, you use "#.00#". If the number is 1.2399f, first it round up to 1.240f, then if you use "#.00#", it strip the trailing zero and output "1.24". If you use "#.000", then it's "1.240". For the record, there's no float exactly 1.233f, it's 1.23300004005.....

Answer (score 0):

Try below:-

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```